# Protecting business logic in webservices

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web-services, business-logic

Is there a way that a hacker or someone who wants to copy my software logic, can reverse engineer the business logic that I have in a webservice?

Is there a way to protect such information?

My development platform in .net asp.net and C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A user of the web service use only the interface and not binary part of your web service. If your web server not safe enough you can place your business logic to the other server on your internal network which is connected through the second network card.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean by "use only the interface and not binary part of your web service" ?

Comment: I means, that your main part with business logic (typically from bin directory) run on the server only. A client can only send requests to the web server and communicate only with interface part of the web service. So access to the business logic is only through a hacker attack theoretically possible. If you place your business logic on a second server which is not accessibly from the internet you will be receive more security.

Answer (score 1):

Binary deployed executables can always be reverse engineered, but the effort to reverse engineer code could be increased by an obscurator.

Here is an example tool: http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator

There are always ways for a hacker or the user of a webservice to get access to the binary. Here I define the user as the individual you sell your solution to.

A webservice client does not have access to the code unless the server is compromised.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the hacker is somehow able to gain read permission to the bin folder on your web server will they be able to pull down the binary file and reverse engineer it.  I agree with Oleg's answer in that if you are really worried about securing the biz logic you should put it on a seperate server and access it through a seperate internal network.